# Activity with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK has been destroyed

Tags: android, service, android-activity, background

I'm using this way to start activity from Service, if my app is background:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FromBackgroundActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

it works perfect,
but if `FromBackgroundActivity` is active and I press Home key it puts all to background.
And if I click on my app in taskbar it restores my app to foreground but without `FromBackgroundActivity`, it is destroyed. (
how can i restore my app from background with `FromBackgroundActivity`?

Answer (score 1):

Try `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));`

It'll clear all the task and go to the FromBackgroundActivity.

Comment: Thank for your answer.but it did not help, when I click on my app in taskbar android kills FromBackgroundActivity